# Why is an additional for loop and else statement unnecessary for iterating through nested arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I am doing challenges on freeCodeCamp.com to sharpen up my coding knowledge. Currently working on my JavaScript Algorithms and Data Structures.

Below is the prompt and my solution to a problem:

prompt:

> We have defined a function, `filteredArray`, which takes `arr`, a nested array, and `elem` as arguments, and returns a new array. `elem` represents an element that may or may not be present on one or more of the arrays nested within `arr`. Modify the function, using a for loop, to return a filtered version of the passed array such that any array nested within `arr` containing `elem` has been removed.

My solution:

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  let newArr = [];
  // Only change code below this line
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].indexOf(elem) == -1) {
      newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
  };
  // Only change code above this line
  return newArr;
}
console.log(filteredArray([
  [3, 2, 3],
  [1, 6, 3],
  [3, 13, 26],
  [19, 3, 9]
], 3));
```

My question: There’s no “issue”. I am just wanting some learning comprehension here. I understand the basis of the problem and what is happening, and I understand my solution. What I don’t understand is how we can iterate through a nested array by just using one for loop. To my understanding, for the following array:

```
[[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]]
```

if I used:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
};
```

we are iterating through the array to each sub array. But to iterate through the subarray, we would have to nest an additional for loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; i < arr[i].length; i++) {
  };
```

after doing that, it would then make sense to have and if/else statement. such as:

```
if (arr[j].indexOf(elem) > 0) {
  return newArr.pop(arr[i]
  } else {
  return newArr.push[i]
};
```

to summarize, I guess I don’t understand why the second for loop and the else statement are not necessary. Maybe I am missing something. Please offer some guidance if you can. thanks in advance. `

Comment: `.indexOf()` is a loop on its own. It's just syntactic sugar over a traditional `for` loop.

Comment: Put another way, how do you think `indexOf()` works if it doesn't have a loop inside its code?

Comment: BTW, instead of `indexOf()`, use `includes()` -- it returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the item is found.

Comment: This is exactly what people new to JavaScript don't understand, that iterative functions such as map, filter, find etc. somehow magically do their stuff without iterating.

Comment: @Barmar so to make sure I understand, indexOf() is a method that has a loop in it already? That's why it works on the above code? furthermore, if I did not use a method provided to me by JavaScript and I wrote my own code for a method to use, then I would have to use a nested for loop as well as an if/else statement as I described above? Essentially, JavaScript has done that work for me already. That makes a ton of sense. Also, I totally wish I used includes() instead. that would have helped a ton as well. Thank you for answering!

Comment: Yes, now you're getting it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, built-in Javascript array methods can iterate on their own. For example, here is almost the same solution but uses .includes() instead of .indexOf():

```
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!arr[i].includes(elem)) {
      newArr.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}
```